# Can .NET TcpListener class receive data sent via SSH (SFTP)

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp, tcplistener

I need to receive and parse data sent over SSH via SFTP in my .NET 4.5 application.  The SFTP server is running Cygwin OpenSSH on a Windows 2008 server.

I know the .NET `TcpListener` class can receive and parse data sent via FTP, but I don't know if this is possible with SFTP, and if `TcpListener` can receive the data, is it necessary or possible to decrypt the data?

Unfortunately, it is a requirement that I receive the data over SSH via SFTP, so requesting to receive the data via FTP or FTPS is not an option.

Comment: IFAIK, `TcpListener` does not receiving data over FTP on its own support either. You have to implement FTP protocol on top of it. The same as with SFTP/SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSH does not offer any triggers you could use to process received files.

All you can do is to monitor local file system, where OpenSSH stores the uploaded (received) files.

Or poll the files over SFTP as @user469104 suggested.

Or use a different SFTP server that supports triggers. Though I do not know any free server that supports this.

Ntb, to use `TcpListener`, you would have to implement SSH/SFTP protocols on your own. What is an immense task.

Comment: Thank you for your reply you did a great job of outlining the limitations I am facing with this task.  As you stated I know I can write a monitoring function in my application which periodically checks for new files on my server, but my concern with doing this is that it may attempt to access a file before it has been completely uploaded to my server, which could cause my application to fail to parse some critical data.  Any suggestions???

Comment: Or, Is there a way to enable detailed logging of activities on my OpenSSH service (Windows 2008 server)?  If so, I am thinking of attempting to read the log file to detect when data is being uploaded to my server.  I wish I could just pull the files from the client's server via SFTP, but that is not an option because I've been tasked with building an intermediate application that must work with the client's existing system.

Comment: Common solution to determining if file upload has finished is to agree with client to upload the file with distinct name/extension (e.g. `.filepart`), renaming the file to final name after upload finishes. Or to upload file to a special folder, moving it to final folder after upload. Though that involves work on client side. Otherwise you can wait some time (1 minute?) after the file appears/changes the last time to hope it's complete.

Comment: Thank you for your advise you helped to set me in the right direction. I've decided to use the .net FileSystemWatcher to detect when changes occur in my SFTP receiving folders, along with a .net FileStream function which verifies that there are no other open connection to the file prior to reading it.  I know there maybe some drawbacks to using these processes but I think it is the best I can without more specific data or actions from the client sending the data.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a third party library, there is no built-in support for SSH or SFTP in .NET.

Also, note that SSH and SFTP are two different protocols. To say that you would receive data over SSH via SFTP sounds weird. Unless you plan on tunneling SFTP traffic over SSH but that would be very unusual.

One option would be to use WinSCP, it can be used to retrieve files over SFTP. It is a native windows command line app but it has a .NET wrapper that allows for automation through .NET.

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library

Comment: I apologize that my initial post was confusing.  I have configured Cygwin OpenSSH as a Windows service to receive files, which must be parsed in my .net application.  I am trying to find a method to detect when files are uploaded to my server via the SSH service, and when the upload of the files have completed.  Of course as you have suggested the WinSCP library is great for retrieving files via SFTP but does not provide any service (that I am aware of) for managing the receipt of files.  Any suggestions, anyone?

Comment: As per the answer, WinSCP has a .NET wrapper that allows for automation through .NET. Using that you can create anything you need to manage receipt of files.

Comment: Please rephrase your question.